# NASM x87 Floating Point Arithmetic Evaluates To 0

Tags: c, assembly, floating-point, nasm, x86-64

I'm new too NASM assembly and I don't know why my assembly code returns 0. Could anyone offer assistance or advice? The code simulates dot product based on the *C* function:

```
double dot(long int n, double x[], double y[])
{
  double sum = 0.0;
  long int i;
  for(i=0; i<n; i++) sum = sum + x[i]*y[i];
  return sum;
} // end dot
```

with values

```
long int n = 4;
double x[4] = {2.0,  3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
double y[4] = {5.0, -3.0, 2.0, 4.0};
double sum;
```

linked to the nasm x86 64-bit assembly code:

```
    extern printf

    section .bss
fltstorage:      resq 1
tempflt:      resq 1

    section .data

dotMsg:         db "dot n= ", 0
fmt_float:      db "%f",10,0
fmt_dig:        db "%ld",10, 0 ; print just one digit, e.g. 0 or 1
fmt_end:        db 10, 0    ; just end line

sumOffset equ 32

    section .text
    global dot              ;for dot function

dot:
    push rbp                                ;push the stack
    mov rbp, rsp                            ;callers stack
    sub rsp, 8                              ;make space for local variables (one quadword)
    push rdi                                ;save registers
    push rsi
;calculations go here
                                            ;RBX is off-limits
    mov rsi, qword [rbp + 28]               ;RSI now contains third argument
    mov rdi, qword [rbp + 20]               ;RDI now contains second argument
    mov rcx, [rbp + 12]                     ;RCX should now contain first argument  (this is a failure point- check it later)

    mov r8, 0                               ;clear results storage

dot_loop:

    mov [fltstorage], rdi                   ;rdi is a pointer to element in x
    fld qword [fltstorage]                  ;nth index of x array to st0

    mov [fltstorage], rsi                   ;rsi is a pointer to element in y
    fmul qword [fltstorage]                 ;multiply ST0 by element from y
    add rdi, 8                              ;increment rdi, go to next element in x
    add rsi, 8                              ;increment rsi, go to next element in y

    mov [fltstorage], r8
    fadd qword [fltstorage]                 ;add cumulative sum to fresh value
    fstp qword [tempflt]                    ;move sum to storage
    mov r8, tempflt                         ;reduce rcx
    cmp rcx, 0                              ;check if it's at the end of the loop
    jg dot_loop                             ;if it is isn't,loop again

    push rdi
    push rsi
    push rax

    ;;;   print r8 to check output
    mov rdi, fmt_float
    mov rsi, r8
    mov rax, 0
    call printf

    pop rax
    pop rsi
    pop rdi

    mov rax, r8                             ;prep result for return
    add rsp, 8                              ;balance out rsp from subtraction up top


    pop rsi                                 ;restore registers
    pop rdi
    mov rsp, rbp                            ;restore initial stack
    pop rbp                                 ;restore B register
    ret
```

Comment: Since this is 64-bit code you should rewrite this to use XMM registers and scalar SSE instructions. You also need to follow the 64-bit calling convention for your OS which you don't appear to be doing.

Comment: What platform is this for?

Comment: Your code is pretty broken even if x87 were appropriate: if `rdi` holds a pointer, then `fld qword [rdi]` loads the double it points to.  `mov [fltstorage], rdi` / `fld [fltstorage]` is a `reinterpret_cast` of a pointer to a double.  Also, it uses static storage instead of the stack space you already reserved.  (If this is for a platform that uses the SysV ABI, there's a red zone of 128B below the stack pointer, so you don't even need to reserve anything.)

Comment: And you're writing 64bit code which looks like it's expecting its args on the stack.  Only the obsolete 32bit ABI does that.  Look at [compiler output from clang](https://godbolt.org/g/aBFWXJ) for your `dot()` function to see how it's done.  It unrolls with four accumulators and scalar intro/cleanup.

Comment: I'm going to echo the question @NateEldredge asked. What Operating System is this on? Windows? OSX? Linux? Other? Is this in fact 64-bit code you have to write (your question does say that), however uncertainty might exist in that you appear to be using a 32-bit calling convention.

Comment: The platform is Linux and it should be 64-bit code. I have since replaced the r8 register with xmm0 to hold floating point however this results in the rest of the dot_loop being incorrect.